# UITabBar not changing color after setNeedsDisplay

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have an UITabBar that needs to be coloured after initialization. 
I use:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:secondaryColor];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:primaryColor];
[[UITabBar appearance] setUnselectedItemTintColor:[secondaryColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
```

This works when the color are available at start time but when I try this after creation this doesn't work until another controller is pushed & poped on the navigation stack.. after that the tabbar is properly colored. How can I force this without push/poping another controller?
I tried setNeedsDisplay on the tabbar but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you dispatching on the main thread?

Comment: yes, that is dispatched on the main thread